# What is the best way to show a video in a post?

Tags: discussion, debates

Suppose I have a question regarding a video, and I think the question is going to be easier to understand by seeing the video.

What is the best way to show a video in a post?

**Edited for more details:**

This is a general question for posting a question/answer with a video that helps clarify the content of the post. If you see there are certain criteria that contributes to different ways of attaching a video into a post, please answer specifying them all. Therefore, this question will cover all of the methods for video posting in the future as well.

Comment: Please provide more details. How long is the video? What the video shows? Where is the video hosted?

Comment: @Wicket Edited for more details.

Comment: Thanks. The question looks too broad for me. Please make it specific. Also, consider using the global search (https://stackexchange.com) to add examples about how video is used on other [se] (including [so]). It's worth to mention that some sites have enabled a feature to embed Youtube videos, like [movies.se] (see https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/631)

Comment: @Wicket It looks fine to me now that I added the details covering all aspects one might have that could change the dicision of showing a video in a post. If I make it more specific, it would be 1 meta question for 1 post with a video. For example, I wanted to post a question with video that is 2 minutes long, shows a single character dancing, and is not hosted anywhere because the file is on my computer. That is going to be edited into this question to be specific, and when I have another question with different video settings, I need to ask like this again. Is that really the better approach?

Answer (score 2):

A common community guideline is that posts should be self-contained. This is because external content may become unavailable in the future, rendering the post unhelpful for readers. The ultimate goal is to create a library of high-quality questions and answers that align with the site's scope. Therefore, it's important to ensure that each post is a good fit.

As a community at GenAI Stack Exchange, we may choose to adopt a norm in which questions that require watching a video hosted elsewhere may be closed, with some exceptions, or be allowed.

At this stage of the site's development, it is crucial to have real posts that showcase when and why video is necessary. This will facilitate meaningful discussions about the site's purpose and functionality rather than hypothetical scenarios that may never happen.

If you are the video creator, you should upload it to a service that allows the community to watch it. Depending on the video's characteristics, it might be uploaded to The Internet Archive (https://archive.org), YouTube, Google Drive, etc. If it's short enough, it might be saved as an animated gif file, and there might be other options.

As mentioned above, at this stage, it looks to me that we should discuss case by case and for that, we need actual posts containing a video or specific details with the video details to allow the community to discuss, first if that post is a good fit for GenAI Stack Exchange and second what video hosting options might be the more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to show a video in a post?

As an embedded animated gif if compressible below 2 MiB, otherwise link to YouTube.